# Traversing array of dictionaries of plist in iOS

Tags: ios, plist, nsdictionary

I am new to iOS programming, I am working on traversing plist. But I can't access a single record in the label.
That is if I want to access only the details of "Amul" then what to write in the if condition

Below is my plist file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"     
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<dict>
    <key>Email Address</key>
    <string>ams@asd.com</string>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Amul</string>
    <key>Phone Number</key>
    <string>984756393</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>Email Address</key>
    <string>cat@se.com</string>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Anoop</string>
    <key>Phone Number</key>
    <string>87453726</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>Email Address</key>
    <string>per@se.com</string>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Bhagesss</string>
    <key>Phone Number</key>
    <string>7684947</string>
</dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

Also am reading all the data in an Array as shown below

```
NSArray *array=[[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];


    if (i<[array count]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [array objectAtIndex:i]);
        NSString *strName=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[array 
  valueForKey:@"Name"]];
        NSString *strPhone=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[array 
  valueForKey:@"Phone Number"]];
        NSString *strEmail=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[array 
  valueForKey:@"Email Address"]];

        lblName.text=strName;
        lblPhone.text=strPhone;
        lblEmail.text=strEmail;

        i++;
}
```

Now what condition should I raise so that only that record is shown whose name I provide in the textfield.
Please help...

Answer (score 2):

Use isEqualToString method on NSString. BTW, you don't have valueForKey method in NSArray! As suggested earlier answer, use dictionary. Here is complete code.

```
NSArray *array=[[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

int i = 0;
while (i<[array count]) {

    NSDictionary *dict = [array objectAtIndex:i];

    if([[dict objectForKey:@"Name"] isEqualToString:@"Amul"])
    {
        lblName.text=strName;
        lblPhone.text=strPhone;
        lblEmail.text=strEmail;
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: I wish I could give you a hundred +1s...I've been searching everywhere trying to figure out how to traverse a plist.  This is the best and most clear example I found.  Thanks applefreak!!!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

There is a mismatch between the data in the plist and the way you are accessing the resulting data structure, it seems to me.

Try to do this:

```
if (i < [array count]) {
   NSDictionary* dict = [array objectAtIndex:i];
   if([[dict valueForKey:@"Name"] isEqualToString:@"Amul"]) {
      ...
```

Comment: Thanks sergio... but isEqualTo doesnot work as it requires an id, also isEqualToString fails with a SIGBART error... any other option..